# Ingress intra-cluster Kubernetes communication

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube, kube-dns, kubernetes-ingress

I have an nginx ingress running in minikube (addon enabled) with a couple pods and services, the ingress has the following configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.info
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: api-service
          servicePort: 80
  - host: web.info
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: web-service
          servicePort: 80
```

When I'm outside the cluster the following works fine:

```
curl --header 'Host: api.info' $(minikube ip)/health
```

But, when I'm inside the cluster, I would expect the containers to be able to talk to each other using their host names listed in my Ingress template. For example, I would expect the following to work, but it doesn't:

```
$ kubectl exec -it web-6c656c58d5-lpxsk /bin/bash
root@web-6c656c58d5-lpxsk:/web# curl api.info/health
```

Instead, it returns results from the actual api.info website, which I have no affiliation. First, can someone please confirm that this is suppose to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `.info` is a generic TLD, this makes DNS resolution messy.
Consider using a protected TLD or your own registered one e.g. `api.example.com`

You should edit your `/etc/hosts` with a line similar to:
`<ip_address> api.info`

or changing `resolv.conf` to prioritise your internal DNS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't answer the question. I was aware that it makes DNS messy, but I didn't know of anything better - anyways it should be able to handle this scenario. I changed my domains to a `api.example`, `web.example`, but the same fundamental problem persists. Updating `/etc/hosts` to point to an ip address doesn't really make sense for inside a Kubernetes container, does it? What ip address would I point to? The same for changing `resolve.conf`

Comment: Do you have kube-dns installed on your minikube? https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/tree/master/deploy/addons/kube-dns

Comment: Yes, I do. `- kube-dns: enabled`

Comment: Generally pod `/etc/`hosts` is inherited from the node running kubelet. It seems your pod is using a public DNS to resolv `api.info`. `resolv.conf` is a way to specify DNS priority i.e. use kubedns first then public dns next.

Comment: Yes, it would seem that, but the one nameserver in `resolv.conf` points to one of the `kube-dns` nameservers: https://gist.github.com/decoursin/bc6646a0208f7fc8c7c08707fb384ad5. Are you even sure that an Ingress host name is suppose to be resolvable from any container within the same namespace?